# Potential Error in the Official Spring Website

Tags: spring, javabeans, alias

Im new to Spring , In the official website of Spring i think there is an error in the example :

alias name="myApp-dataSource" alias="subsystemA-dataSource"

alias name="myApp-dataSource" alias="subsystemB-dataSource"

it should be :

alias name="subsystemA-dataSource" alias="myApp-dataSource"

alias name="subsystemB-dataSource" alias="myApp-dataSource"

The link : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-class

Please can any one confirm this or not.

Comment: can you be more clear about what is the problem?

Comment: well, I do not confirm that is an error.

Comment: i copy past the example for you to understand

Comment: Hi @backdoor i post the all example

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK can you explain to me why ?

Answer (score 0):

I copy past the example from the Spring Framework Documentation :

`<alias name="fromName" alias="toName"/>`

In this case, a bean (in the same container) named fromName may also, after the use of this alias definition, be referred to as toName.

For example, the configuration metadata for subsystem A may refer to a DataSource by the name of subsystemA-dataSource. The configuration metadata for subsystem B may refer to a DataSource by the name of subsystemB-dataSource. When composing the main application that uses both these subsystems, the main application refers to the DataSource by the name of myApp-dataSource. To have all three names refer to the same object, you can add the following alias definitions to the configuration metadata:

**`<alias name="myApp-dataSource" alias="subsystemA-dataSource"/>`

`<alias name="myApp-dataSource" alias="subsystemB-dataSource"/>`**

Comment: Did any one Know ??